# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sendgrid_backend'

Tags: django, pip, sendgrid, modulenotfounderror

when my server is running im getting this error.

my settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "sendgrid_backend.SendgridBackend"
SENDGRID_API_KEY=' my api key'
```

i installed sendgrid by:

```
pip install django-sendgrid-v5
```

and when i runing `pip list` i see that:

```
Package            Version
------------------ -------
asgiref            3.6.0
autopep8           2.0.2
distlib            0.3.6
Django             4.2.1
django-sendgrid-v5 1.2.2
filelock           3.8.0
pip                23.1.2
platformdirs       2.5.3
pycodestyle        2.10.0
python-http-client 3.3.7
sendgrid           6.10.0
sendgrid-django    4.2.0
setuptools         65.5.0
sqlparse           0.4.4
starkbank-ecdsa    2.2.0
tzdata             2023.3
virtualenv         20.16.6
```

and i got the same error.

Comment: try uninstalling `sendgrid-django`, when i tried to install your list as a `requirements.txt` that threw a bunch of errors.

Also, try doing `python manage.py shell` + `import sendgrid_backend` + `print(sendgrid_backend.SendgridBackend)` and see if that at least works

Comment: I see you have `virtualenv` in your dependencies there. Did you make sure your virtual environment for this project is activated, and that you have installed the sendgrid package while the virtual environment was activated?